# How to align text in button and align button to input feild

Tags: html, css

I have a input field & button. However, there are two problems.

- The text in the button is not centered.
- The button is never the same height as the input.

To visualize it:

[image: for visual people....]

Ok, I also put together a super convenient [fiddle to play with this](https://jsfiddle.net/ny9e84ed/).

How can I fix these problems? Make it look "**perfectly aligned**". I tried fiddling around with height settings, though was unsuccessful.

Code in that fiddle:

```
HTML:
<body style="background-color: #5a6b7d">
<div style="text-align: center">
    <h1 id='format' style="margin-top: 50px;">Welcome to our site</h1>
    <p id='format' style="">this is a site</p>
    <br>
    <h2 id="format"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Type your username <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type a username" style="font-size: 140%; text-align: center;" align="center">
    <a href="index.php"><button id="playbutton">Play</button></a>
</div>
</body>

CSS:
button[id=playbutton]{
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;

        height: 40px;
    }

    button:hover{
        background-color: darkgreen;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css for your green button :

```
button[id=playbutton]{
background-color: #4CAF50;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 8px 32px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 16px;
margin: 4px 2px;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 5px;
position: relative;
top: -2px;
}
```

use `position: relative; top:1px; /* adjust this top` to repositioning the button

Answer (score 0):

```css
button[id=playbutton]{
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
       
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;

        height: 40px;
    }

    button:hover{
        background-color: darkgreen;
    }
    #username{
    height: 40px;
    padding:0px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .input-fields{
    display:inline-flex;
    }
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #5a6b7d">
<div style="text-align: center">
    <h1 id='format' style="margin-top: 50px;">Welcome to our site</h1>
    <p id='format' style="">this is a site</p>
    <br>
  
    <h2 id="format"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Type your username <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
      <div class="input-fields">
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Type a username" style="font-size: 140%; text-align: center;" align="center">
    <a href="index.php"><button id="playbutton">Play</button></a>
    <div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
button[id=playbutton]{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 40px;
    /* New */
    padding: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

The padding 0px will center the text inside the button and the width and height you can use to define the button size. This is an good option for centering if you dont know the exact size of a picture or other things.

Here is the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vLbbkcna/3/

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your button CSS with this:

```
button[id=playbutton]{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
    line-height: 35px;
    width: 80px;
}
```